# why do I get a hash instead of an array when using nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I'm using nested attributes in may rails project but when I submit a form I get the _attributes as a hash of hashes not an array of hashes like it's said in the documentation, which means rails can't get the params for the new object.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"oLy4lJyXBgKiUI+TlQgEGIRNLeNOG5WqiHLqYNiZYe1JXC7+/j02ZDsBAnVZCAgeUJw6B5iTXxkzV1XzUIDn+w==",
"form"=>{"title"=>"test 3", "questions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"question_text"=>"hello what?"}}},
"commit"=>"Create Form"}
```

like in the code above :questions_attributes should have been an array not a hash with an element called '0'

the form code:

```
  = form_for(setup_form(@form)) do |f|
    = error_messages_for(f.object)
    = f.label(:title, 'Title')
    = f.text_field(:title)
    = f.fields_for(:questions) do |q|
      = q.label(:question_text, 'Question')
      = q.text_field(:question_text)
    = f.submit "Create Form", :class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary"
```

Comment: Can you post the form where you are rendering the nested attributes?

Comment: I added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not read whole doc. From [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

> Nested attributes for an associated collection can also be passed in
>   the form of a hash of hashes instead of an array of hashes:
>
> ```
> Member.create(
>   name: 'joe',
>   posts_attributes: {
>     first:  { title: 'Foo' },
>     second: { title: 'Bar' }
>   }
> )
> ```
>
> has the same effect as
>
> ```
> Member.create(
>   name: 'joe',
>   posts_attributes: [
>     { title: 'Foo' },
>     { title: 'Bar' }
>   ]
> )
> ```
>
> The keys of the hash which is the value for :posts_attributes are
>   ignored in this case. However, it is not allowed to use 'id' or :id
>   for one of such keys, otherwise the hash will be wrapped in an array
>   and interpreted as an attribute hash for a single post.
>
> Passing attributes for an associated collection in the form of a hash
>   of hashes can be used with hashes generated from HTTP/HTML parameters,
>   where there may be no natural way to submit an array of hashes.

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior of nested attributes. If you add more questions fields to the form, output will be as :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"oLy4lJyXBgKiUI+TlQgEGIRNLeNOG5WqiHLqYNiZYe1JXC7+/j02ZDsBAnVZCAgeUJw6B5iTXxkzV1XzUIDn+w==",
"form"=>{"title"=>"test 3", "questions_attributes"=>{
  "0"=>{"question_text"=>"hello what?"}, 
  "1"=>{"question_text"=>"Hi"},
  "2"=>{"question_text"=>"Hello"}},
"commit"=>"Create Form"}
```